# Error collection is modified, cannot perform enumeration on sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, foreach, splist

not sure why i get the above error, i know its because of UpdateWorkflowAssociation is inside the foreach but i need it that way 
A simple help will be highly appreciated

```
                        `siteName = "http://xyz";

                        newCleanupDays = 5;
                        assoCounter = 0;
                        using (wfSite = new SPSite(siteName))
                        {
                            using (wfWeb = wfSite.OpenWeb())
                            {

                               //wfList = wfWeb.Lists[libraryName];
                                SPListCollection collList = wfWeb.Lists; //Open Lists
                                SPWorkflowAssociation _wfAssociation = null;

                                foreach (SPList oList in collList)
                                {
                                    if (oList.WorkflowAssociations.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation a in oList.WorkflowAssociations)
                                        {
                                            if (a.Name != null || a.Name != string.Empty)
                                            {
                                                a.AutoCleanupDays = newCleanupDays;
                                                _wfAssociation = a;
                                                assoCounter++;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                _wfAssociation = a;
                                            }

                                        }
                                        oList.UpdateWorkflowAssociation(_wfAssociation);
                                    }

                                }
                                System.Console.WriteLine("\n" + wfAssoName + ": " + assoCounter.ToString() + " workflow association(s) changed successfuly!\n");
                            }
                        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
foreach (SPList oList in collList)
```

simply write

```
foreach (SPList oList in collList.ToList())
```

That way you will iterate over a copy which is *not* modified during the iteration, but the *real* collection can be updated.

Comment: collList is SPlistcollection it does not have ToList() method

Comment: @mainurajkehtehai: It doesn’t need one. It’s an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. Just add `using System.Linq;` at the top. (If `SPlistcollection` doesn’t implement `IEnumerable<SPList>`, consider implementing it.)

Comment: I fixed it by the below code as @Timwi said created a copy and iterated that list for modification.

@Timwi: i would like know more on IEnumerable<T> ..you know some kind of study guide

Thanks

`List<SPList> itemsEnum = new List<SPList>();
  foreach (SPList oList in collList) {
     if (oList.WorkflowAssociations.Count > 0) {
         itemsEnum.Add(oList); }                                        }
foreach (SPList var in itemsEnum) {`

Comment: After iterating through copy list these code although does update original list "oList" not sure  why ? cannu pls help

Comment: Your sentence does not make sense. Sorry.

Comment: Not an issue actually The workflows on which i tested these code were in error state so i thought the above code is not working ....but it is working ...thanks for your reply. I Appreciate thse